# Avoid Typescript complaining about unassigned value that will never be unassigned

Tags: typescript, rxjs

So I have a function that works as a shorthand for selecting values from synchronous observable streams.

The complete function looks like this:

```
export function select<T>(inStream: Observable<T>): T {
  let value: T;

  race(
    inStream,
    throwError(
      new Error(
        select.name + " expects a synchronous stream. Received an asynchronous stream."
        )
      )
    )
    .pipe(take(1))
    .subscribe(val => {
      value = val;
    });

  return value;  
}
```

It works as expected and throws an error if the inStream is not synchronous, meaning I either always get the value in the latest/currrent emission OR an error.

However typescript complains about the value is being used before it is assigned. I could understand Typescript not being clever enough to pick up on how I'm forcing synchronicity or an error, and testing shows that the value will always be set correctly when the stream is in fact synchronous, or we would get an error.

So how should I avoid this silly Typescript-derp? I'm not very tempted to put an ignore on it, though I'm considering this if no one has any great suggestions.

Anyway thanks!

(Demo to show the functionality working as expected so we can focus on solving the typescript solution instead of being sidetracked by what I'm doing with the code:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-select-demo?file=index.ts

select is used twice in this example. First on a sync stream and gets the value. Second time on an async stream and throws an error and does not return any value. Perfect.)

Comment: Never mind the typescript complaint, this code is not correct. Everything inside the stream is async, the code outside of it is synchronous. So the return will fire immediately

Comment: It's not. Try it out if you want. `race` with `throwError` as second argument makes the function throw an error if the instream is not synchronous. You always get either the value or an error, never asynchronous behavior. (throwError ALWAYS fires synchronously, and if race gets two synchronous streams as parameters it will choose by the order the streams were supplied, meaning if instream is sync it will use that stream, otherwise it will immediately throw an error)

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-select-demo created a quick stackblitz to demonstrate that it does in fact complete synchronously. Check the console log and see that it does indeed print Hello world. The first time we use it is on a sync stream and it returns the emission as expected. Second time is with an async stream and it throws an error and the value is never set. So the code is 100% correct and works as expected.

Comment: @LarsHoldaas can't you just use a bang like `return value!;`, or are you using an older version of TypeScript? See [this example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/C4TwDgpgBAShDOB7ANgNwgHgCoD4oF4oAKVAQ2QFcIAuKLKAHygAUAnRAWwEt4IAZLgGtMuAJQE8qRFwAmAbgCwAKFCRYEAFYQAxsALFWEUkgB2tAKKt2rcfknT5y5QDMKJ3V0QmoYbfGz6pCYgOESitADabJw8IjgANOpIaHGJcFq6ALpQAN7KUFDIEHqGyei0JORUtPRM0dy8AsLYOLb2sopKBUUlmjrAFWSUNFCW1m1QUh1OXVCGwBSs3hH5BVAmEADuLOwNcUREAPqlKOiJx326E3mza3MIp9CEF2UQnXcFhhl6z1-972sAL6ieKrT4PFIAQlBt3u30hq0ynUBMx6UAiYESpSxmmyhF88DCnSAA).

Comment: Yeah that totally works! I've never seen that before, need to check the documentation I guess. If you want to answer I'll mark it as correct

Answer (score 0):

Because `subscribe` is often *expected* to be used asynchronously, I think the cleanest solution would be to convert it to a Promise and return that Promise:

```
export function select<T>(inStream: Observable<T>): Promise<T> {
    return race(
        inStream,
        throwError(
            new Error(
                select.name + " expects a synchronous stream. Received an asynchronous stream."
            )
        )
    )
        .pipe(take(1))
        .toPromise();
}
```

Of course, you'd also need to call `.then` or `await` the Promise in the consumer of `select`.

You could also return the observable and use its methods instead, if that's more suited for your use case.

This also makes the code more extensible if/when you need to tweak it to work with asynchronous streams as well.

Comment: I prefer not to mix Promises into my codebase. I use streams for 99% of operations, mostly asynchronous, but sometimes I need to get values from synchronous streams (such as behavior subjects or observables that only map from observables) and this short-hand syntax works pretty well (`const id = select(id$)`). So functionally I don't see any need to change anything, just want to appease typescript if possible

Comment: I also strongly disagree with subscribe being expected to be used asynchronously. Unless the creator function or any operators in the pipe explicitly introduce asynchronous behavior observable streams behave synchronously. And a lot of operators etc. also force synchronous behavior.